# How to add a premade static page to your gatsby project?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have a react/graphql/gatsby project.

Separate from the rest of the project I have a `magazine` folder. In that folder there is an `index.html` file and a bunch of other folders with a lot of js/css/media files.

I want to add this folder to my project so that I can access contents of the folder via `websiteName/magazine` link. To do that I put `magazine` folder inside of `static` folder of my project. That did not work. My guess is that I somehow need to handle this directory with gatsby config but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to configure Gatsby to serve files from the `static` folder in development if you want to access this page using the dev server. To do that, add the following to your gatsby-node.js file:

```js
const express = require(`express`)

// Enable development support for serving HTML from `./static` folder
exports.onCreateDevServer = ({ app }) => {
  app.use(express.static(`static`))
}
```

Comment: still works like a charm. Kudos!!

Answer (score 0):

[Gatsby is a folder interpreted path](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-project-structure/) so, everything that is inside `/pages` folder, will be converted as a page following the folder structure.

Given an old-fashioned `index.html`, if you don't want to convert it to a JavaScript file, you can create a `magazine.js` file inside `/pages` and paste there the HTML as a JSX.

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/Layout/Layout';

const Magazine= props => {
  return <Layout>
        // paste here your old HTML
  </Layout>;
};

export default Magazine;
```

Regarding the assets (CSS, images, and JavaScript files) of that `index.html`, they should be placed in the [static folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/) and you may need to change the old path to refer to the new ones.

It's tedious work but your Magazine page will be perfectly valid inside a JSX file and wrapped by a `<Layout>` component will get the same structure as the other pages.

Comment: The problem here is that magazine folder was prepared by the third party and is obfuscated. Is there some way to use that folder the same we use netlify cms - we have admin folder in static and then we handle it with gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms inside confug file?